# Access to Apex controller for public community lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, profile

I have a public facing LWC in a community that you do not need to login in to see. I'm trying to retrieve data based on a recordId. I'm getting an error saying I don't have access to that apex controller. Normally, I'd just add that controller to a permission set or profile, but since there is no login happening, how do I allow access to that controller for users just clicking on the link and not logging in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You add that permission to the Guest User that represents the community. Go to Setup | User Interface | Sites and Domains | Sites | **Site Name** | Public Access Settings, then edit this profile to assign any resources public users should have access to.